# jQuery AJAX $.post not working with .click() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Having a little difficulty with my ajax request. It seems that the $.post method is simply not working, no request is being sent. Nothing is showing in firebug either.

I can get this to work:

```
   $('.comment-remove').click(function (evt) {

        evt.preventDefault();
        var sure = confirm('Are you sure your want to remove your comment from this thread?');

        if(sure) {              
            var comment_id = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(member_id);
        }
    });
```

but not this:

```
   $('.comment-remove').click(function (evt) {

        evt.preventDefault();
        var sure = confirm('Are you sure your want to remove your comment from this thread?');

        if(sure) {
            var comment_id = $(this).attr('id');

            $.post('comment.php', { comment_id: comment_id }, function(data) {
                if (data === 'success') {
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    alert('Unable to remove comment at this time.');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And HTML is:

```
<a class="comment-remove" id="<?php echo $comment_id; ?>">Remove my comment</a>
```

Comment: Did you check the console for errors, and what does comment.php look like ?

Comment: This isn't super important, but it is much faster to do `this.id` than `$(this).attr('id')`. http://jsperf.com/browser-diet-this-attr-id-vs-this-id/12

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be:

```
$.post('comment.php', { comment_id: comment_id }, function(data) {
  if (data === 'success') {
    alert(data);
  } else {
    alert('Unable to remove comment at this time.');
  }
})
```

See the extra `)` I added? It matches the `(` in `$.post(` at the start. You were missing it, it's always easy to do. Your console should be able to tell you about this kind of thing.

Comment: See how I say 'It should be:'?

Comment: sorry I got it upside down.

Comment: @thenewseattle its cool, helped me make sure I was clear in what I was saying.

Comment: thanks guys, its always the most obvious solution that I don't see

Answer (score 1):

Your post call is missing a closing parenthesis.  Try this:

```
    $('.comment-remove').click(function (evt) {

        evt.preventDefault();
        var sure = confirm('Are you sure your want to remove your comment from this thread?');

        if(sure) {
            var comment_id = $(this).attr('id');

            $.post('comment.php', { comment_id: comment_id }, function(data) {
                if (data === 'success') {
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    alert('Unable to remove comment at this time.');
                }
            })
        }
    });
```